# Phone reboots when I navigate past Falkirk

Tags: cyanogenmod, reboot, google-maps-navigation

Occasionally when navigating, my phone will freeze (the display and also the music, if it's playing) then reboot a few seconds later.  I realised today that while it's happened in other places, driving past Falkirk seems to trigger it.

My question is: Given that I'm away from my PC, and it doesn't happen very often, how can I diagnose the (general, rather than location-specific) issue?  I've got an HTC Desire running CM7 and I'm comfortable using a shell.

Answer (score 1):

Try turning off wifi completely then driving past Falkirk several times.  I'm surprised this happens with CM but my experience so far with Gingerbread on the Galaxy Note is that it's very stable so long as you don't have wifi enabled or use an SD card.  (I am trying to remain objective)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion -- I'll try it out when next I'm passing, but I think Juice Defender should be turning WiFi off anyway.